# quicksight average count, receiving 'unavailable' on all rows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-quicksight

I have a table like this on my spice:

```
schema name  deal_id
a            1
a            1
a            2
b            1
b            2
b            3
```

I need to generate a diagram showing the average number of deals per each schema,

this is what I think should make it work:

```
avgOver(count({deal_id}), [{schema_name}])
```

but it doesn't in the dataset I see the column with all 'unavailable' values.

I get the same result with this:

```
avgOver(countOver({deal_id}, [{schema_name}]), [{schema_name}])
```

I'm not sure what's the problem,

the calculated result I need for my chart would be like (with the data above):

```
schema name         average number of deals
a                   1,5
b                   1.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choose a visualisation that has a group by field well and put the schema name here, put the deal_id in the value field well and choose the aggregation type of average to achieve what you want

Comment: thanks, but this averages the actual integers in deal_id rather than the count of equal deal_ids in each schema

Comment: ok, it's my mistake in the question actually, the figures need to be different, a 1.5 and b 1

Comment: ah, you would just do the same for a calculated field that would be distinctCount(deal_id) then

Comment: Hang on I am confused now, should a be 1.5 or 0.66?

Comment: I need the  average number of rows per each schema_name having the same schema_name and deal_id, 

this is what I got now, and looks like we're getting somewhere: 

`distinctCountOver({deal_id}, [{deal_id}, {schema_name}], PRE_FILTER)`

so for schema (A) would be 2 and 1 rows per deal, total 3 div 2(deals) = 1,5

Comment: Ok so I can get the numbers you are looking for with countOver({deal_id}, [{schema name}], PRE_FILTER) / avgOver(distinctCountOver({deal_id}, [{schema name}], PRE_FILTER), [{schema name}], PRE_FILTER) and Average aggregation on the visual like above, will update the answer now but not too sure on the exact explanation now

Comment: brilliant, thanks, if you can make it answer I'll mark it as correct :)

Comment: have sorted that now :) will need to ask AWS about this distinctCountOver function

Answer (score 1):

Calculated fields will show as unavailable in the dataset as they usually rely on the visualisations using the data.

By putting this in a table visualisation in an analysis you can get what you are expecting to see

Comment: uhm, ok, thanks, I tried what you mentioned, but in the visual it says: `Table claculation attribute reference(S) are missing in field wells`

not sure what that means

Comment: It means drag (or click) schema name and deal_id into your visualisation and then present it however you see fit. As mentioned calculated fields need the context of the fields they rely on. In your example you are grouping by schema name if that makes sense

Comment: uhm thanks, now I can see a visual, but I need the average count per deal, if I insert the deal_id in the visual then I'll just have a count. how can I average these counts?

Comment: Hang on, I have a better answer, it doesn't even require a calculated field

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
countOver({deal_id}, [{schema name}], PRE_FILTER) / avgOver(distinctCountOver({deal_id}, [{schema name}], PRE_FILTER), [{schema name}], PRE_FILTER)
```

as a calculated field and Average the value (as shown in the screenshots), this will get the answer you are looking for. I have never heard of distinctCountOver before and there seems to be no documentation on it? But this definitely gets the values you need in (I think) the way you want to calculate them

[image: 3]